# How to display the content of the cache in vim

Tags: vim

Anyone knows how to display the list of content in the cache, which is used for cut,copy,paste,undo,redo etc., in vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the registers that are used in copy/paste operations you can use:

```
:reg
```

It shows the content of every registry.

The undo/redo history of vim is saved in a tree format and can be viewed with:

```
:undolist
```

But it is not presented very handy, so you could make use of plugins like [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree).

If you would like to see the command history, use:

```
:history
```